# How To Set A New Default Tab As A Specific Spreadsheet on Google Sheets (Not As A Blank Page)?

Tags: google-sheets

How do I set a new default tab to be a specific spreadsheet that I made with formulas, etc.., so that every time I click a new tab, it opens up this specific spreadsheet, instead of a blank Google sheet page?

Is there a VBA code?

Answer (score 0):

grab the sheet tab and move it to the front:

[image: 0]

### _______________________________________________________________

if this is a question about setting up a template as the default page for every newly created spreadsheet - that's not possible. templates are available for individual selection under this button:

[image: 0]

### _______________________________________________________________

to actually "clone" the sheet you will need to use a script. you can try something like:

```
function cloneGoogleSheet() {

  var name = "labnol";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Template').copyTo(ss);

  /* Before cloning the sheet, delete any previous copy */
  var old = ss.getSheetByName(name);
  if (old) ss.deleteSheet(old); // or old.setName(new Name);

  SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // Utilities.sleep(2000);
  sheet.setName(company);

  /* Make the new sheet active */
  ss.setActiveSheet(sheet);

}
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your response. I see what you did here. But this is not what I am wanting to do. Let me reexplain what I am trying to do: By default, if I click on the + sign on the bottom of Google Sheets, a new 'blank sheet' will appear. I do not want this. If I click the + sign, I want the default sheet to be set to a specific sheet that I've already created and that contains my formulas. How do I do this? If this is still unclear, here is a video on YouTube that explains my idea using Excel: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uQaFgOg5kAQ

Comment: Hello. Does your second edited response at the top apply to what I just wrote above here?

Comment: This is very very close! Thank you so much for the code. So it did recreate the sheet that I wanted when I ran the code. But when I manually click the "Add Sheet" icon, it still gives a new "blank page." I want it where when I click the Add Sheet icon, it pulls up the specific sheet that I want. How can this be done?

Comment: P.S. I did also get an error message after running the code. It said: ReferenceError: "company" is not defined. (line 12, file "Code"). I do not know if this would be related to the response that I sent you before this one.

Comment: I don't see any possibility to stack it under "+" button best you can do is to have it under  custom menu and call for it from there: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjR0F.png (ps: you can probably delete line 12)

Comment: Thank you so much for your assistance. I really appreciate it. It is interesting that you say that you don't see any possibility to stack it under the "+" sign or the "Add Icon." How could this be the case, when this can be done on Excel, like the video I sent? Isn't there some custom function that can be created and that can trigger the add icon to respond a certain way?

Comment: Excel is kinda different. google app script is not so flexible as VBA. google app script cant interact with Google Sheets GUI. the only exception is to insert a custom menu into GUI menu

Answer (score 0):

From my ad hoc trying, Google Sheet seems to determine the default Tab by the creation time. My simple solution is to copy/delete any Tab that is older than the desired new default.

For example, we have a Tab "New Default" that we want to set to the new default. Assume there are only a small number of Tabs (3 Tabs) created before the "New Default" Tab, and all other Tabs were created after the "New Default" tab.

```
(1) Create three new empty tabs. 
(2) Copy over the three tabs created before the "new default" Tab, 
    so that we do not lose them. Then delete these three tabs. 

Now the "New Default" becomes the default tab when open the link to the spreadsheet.
```

Note:
Of course, this approach has limitations and may need a script to do the copy/delete. Or even better if Google Sheet team adds support to set default though GUI directly.

Alternatives:
Before I came up with this low-tech solution, I also tried using a Google App Script `.setActiveSheet("New Default")` method on start. It works for the jumping; however, when people comment in the "New Default" tab, I got a notification in email. When clicking the comment, it jumps to the top of the default tab, which is annoying since it loses focus to the comments text.